# Populate a datatable starting from the second column

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable that retrieves json data from an api. The first column of the table should only contain a checkbox. However, when retrieving the data it populates the first column as well.

[image]

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/o44x', function(json) {
      $('#parametrictable').DataTable({
      data : json.data,
      columns : json.columns,

      columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    } ],
    select: {
        style:    'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
   })
 });
```

Is there any way that I can set that the data should only populate starting from the second column, leaving the first column to only contain the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this issue by updating the api or in your js code just updating the `data` key value to `null` for first object in the `json.columns` array like:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/o44x', function(json) {
   json.columns[0].data = null;
   json.columns[0].defaultContent = '';

   $('#parametrictable').DataTable({
      data: json.data,
      columns: json.columns,
      .... your rest of code
   })
});
```

**EDIT:**

> I meant what your suggestion only did was hide the data that was overlapping with the checkbox. I don't want it hidden. I want the first column to be, by default, only checkboxes. and the overlapping data should be on the 2nd column.

You can update your API like this to achieve that:

```
"columns": [
   {
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": ""
   },
   {
      "data": "DT_RowId",
      "title": "Id"
   },
   {
      "data": "supplier",
      "title": "supplier"
   },
   {
      "data": "color",
      "title": "color"
   }
],
```

Or, you can update your code without modifying your API like:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/o44x', function(json) {

   // Add object for checkbox at first position
   json.columns.unshift({"data": null, "defaultContent": ""});

   $('#parametrictable').DataTable({
      data: json.data,
      columns: json.columns,
      ....your rest of code
   })
});
```

Comment: this only removed the data on the first column. i still need the data, just not on the first column.

Comment: You can easily get selected row data like: `table.rows('.selected').data();`. Here is a demo: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvj6nybx/). Select a row using checkbox and then click on `Get Selected Rows` button and it shows the selected row data.

Comment: no, i meant what your suggestion only did was hide the data that was overlapping with the checkbox. i dont want it hidden. i want the first column to be, by default, only checkboxes. and the overlapping data should be on the 2nd column.

Comment: Then you can simply update your api to pass new object in next index. I have updated the code to show that and you will then not need to make any changes in the js code.

Comment: but what if i don't have control over the api, which means i can't update it?

Comment: You can simply add a new object for that in the first position. Code updated.